# Mockito matcher : isNull counterpart of anyList

Tags: junit, mockito, matcher

Is there an `isNull()` matcher counterpart for `anyList()`/`anyListOf(Class<T>)`? With the code snippet below, is this even possible or am I doing it wrong.

```
@Mock private Calling calling;

@Test
public void test() {
    final Object VALUE_ONE = new Object();
    final Object VALUE_TWO = null;

    when(calling.read(any(), anyList(), anyList)).thenReturn(VALUE_ONE);

    // Should be 
    // when(calling.read(any(), anyList(), isNull())).thenReturn(VALUE_TWO);
    when(calling.read(any(), anyList(), anyList)).thenReturn(VALUE_TWO);

    TestClass resposne = TestHelper.read(calling, 1l);
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is an isNull argument matcher: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.19/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNull() which is designed to match null arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this in Mockito..

```
Mockito.when(mo.read(Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.eq(null))).thenReturn(VALUE_ONE);
```